# Amending json file line by line gives error UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that I want to update line by line but I am getting the error UnsupportedOperation: not readable when I try to run the function below.

```
def update_json(json_file):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode ='w') as tmp:
        with open(json_file) as f:
            print(json_file)
            for json_line in f:
                data = json.loads(json_line)
                if populate_tags(data, param):
                    tmp.write(json.dumps(data) + '\n')

        tmp.seek(0)
        with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(tmp.read())
```

the function used for updating the line is:

```
def populate_tags(data, param_values):
    tags={}        
    for l in data['targets']:
        item = l['item'].strip().lower()
        text = l['text'].strip().lower()
        d={'type': item, 'text_value': text}
        key_value = str(d).strip().lower()
        tag = param_values.get(key_value)       
        if tag is None:
            continue        
        tag = str(tag).replace('"','')        
      
        tags[item] = tag
        
        tags[item] = literal_eval(tags[label])
           
        
    data['options'] = {'Tags': dict(tags)}
    
    
    return bool(tags)
```

exception code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-b4c1e92652ac> in <module>
     22 
     23 for filename in files:
---> 24     update_json(filename)

<ipython-input-65-b4c1e92652ac> in update_json(json_file)
     13             tmp.seek(0)
     14             with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
---> 15                 f.write(tmp.read())
     16 
     17 

UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: Why you are not using `json_file` parameter inside your `updade_json` function?

Comment: Please [show the complete exception traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), formatted as code.

Comment: json_file is a typo. I'll fix that/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tempfile.TemporaryFile` is opened with the incorrect mode, `"w"`: write-only. The error output makes this clear since the only read operation on line 15 is `tmp.read()`. You need to open `tmp` with `mode="r+"` in order to read and write.

```py
def update_json(json_file):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode ='r+') as tmp:
        with open(json_file) as f:
            print(json_file)
            for json_line in f:
                data = json.loads(json_line)
                if populate_tags(data, param):
                    tmp.write(json.dumps(data) + '\n')

        tmp.seek(0)
        with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(tmp.read())
```

Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on file open modes.